# Unable to resolve class targetSdkVersion

Tags: android, azure, ionic-framework, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We use Microsoft Azure Pipelines for building Ionic apps for both ios and android. Unfortunately we encounter the following error while building the android app.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/vsts/work/1/s/android/capacitor-cordova-android-plugins/build.gradle' line: 21

* What went wrong:
Could not compile build file '/home/vsts/work/1/s/android/capacitor-cordova-android-plugins/build.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  build file '/home/vsts/work/1/s/android/capacitor-cordova-android-plugins/build.gradle': 21: unable to resolve class targetSdkVersion 
   @ line 21, column 26.
             targetSdkVersion targetSdkVersion = project.hasProperty('targetSdkVersion') ? rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion : 29
```

The strange part is that several days ago it worked without any problems. Commands used to generate the APK

```
sudo npx jetify

sudo ionic capacitor sync android

cd android && gradle wrapper && sudo ./gradlew assembleRelease `//this is where it fails`
```

Answer (score 33):

Strange it is indeed.  I have the same issue without any good explanation, but I also have a workable fix.  Replacing the line

`targetSdkVersion targetSdkVersion = project.hasProperty('targetSdkVersion') ? rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion : 29`

with

`targetSdkVersion project.hasProperty('targetSdkVersion') ? rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion : 29`

works and it makes some more sense to me than the assignment.

Edit:  apparently this is the correct fix, a recent pull request in the capacitor repository does the same: https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/pull/4788 or the fixing https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/pull/4788/commits/250fdcf03be6510dd629a91a98b5220e14d31664

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I searched for the text and I found it in the node_modules directory. Don't think that's the right way to replace the line.. or is it?

Comment: Thx Man ! I resolve my problem with that !

Comment: I resolve my problem with that !

Answer (score 0):

Ionic App generate some files in folder capacitor-android (if you use capacitor). In this folder, open the manifests/AndroidManisfest.xml and add `android:exported="true"` where you have  without the `android:exported`.
The issue is because Capacitor did not yet add this new requirement in the implementation for Android build script.